# Excel file gets corrupted after overwrite in Android with apache poi

Tags: java, android, excel, apache-poi

I want to overwrite an excel file, but the overwritten file gets corrupted. I am working with android studio and I want to save information into single excel file. Below is my code:

```
private void saveIntoExcel(String fileName, String[] data) {
    try {
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + getString(R.string.app_name) + "/" + fileName;

        InputStream inp = new FileInputStream(new File(path));

        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(inp);
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        HSSFRow row;

        row = sheet.createRow(sheet.getLastRowNum() + 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            HSSFCell cell = row.createCell(i);
            cell.setCellValue(data[i]);
        }

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        File file;

        file = new File(path);
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

        workbook.write(fos);
        fos.close();        

        showToast(str_success);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        showToast(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I tested this code with excel files on pc and works perfectly, but in android the files gets corrupted.

Comment: Are you able to include the error you're seeing on Android? If so please edit your Q and include it.

Comment: @xlm Code runs without any error on logcat, the program run like if all is ok, but when I try to open the file in the pc, Office tell me that the file is corrupted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache POI does not fully support in-place writing of the changed file the way you try to do it.

There is discussion about providing this via a new write() method, but currently you will need to write to a different file to avoid corrupting things during closing the objects. After the workbook is closed you can move the new file over the old one if necessary.

See [some related discussion](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/02ed79e9fb33ee2425b91b12e6d13def3494c145bd1285da1df4e87f@%3Cdev.poi.apache.org%3E) and [this bug](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57919).